# Parsing CSV file with html code in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

I have a CSV file with `Id key` and `Long desc`. The `Id key` is just a string but the `Long desc` is HTML code.

My goal is to parse the CSV file into JSON. (See **Output**)

The thing is that I cant split it on `"` because there are some attributes like `color: ""red""` and some of the text include `"` for example `Charger "15W"`. My other idea was to split `;` that is behind the `Id key` example `KE4I2-21;` but again there are some HTML lines that include `;` like: `&nbsp;`

I'm using node.js and I tried to use some CSV to JSON packages converters but they didn't manage to parse this data.

Any idea how I can manage to convert this odd CSV file to JSON?
(I know that my Output example isn't correct because I'm opening and closing `"`)

I started by replacing all `""` with `'` like this: `.replace(/""/g, "'")`

**CSV file (desc.csv)**

```
Id key;Long desc

KE4I2-21;"<p color=""red""><strong>Charger "15W" - Black</strong></p>

<iframe src=""https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX"" width=""560"" height=""315"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen=""allowfullscreen""></iframe>

<p><strong>More</strong>:&nbsp;</p>

<ul>

<li><strong>List</li>

<li><strong>M&auml;rke</strong>: SiGN</li>

</ul>"

LE0PP;"<p>Type-C charger<br /> - OnePlus 2<br /></p>

<p><em>Warning</em></p>"

T12-XRE2;"<h2>&nbsp;</h2>

<h2><strong>Car Charger</strong></h2>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>

<p><strong>Assets:</strong></p>

<ul>

<li><strong>Something</strong>Nice</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>

<li><strong>Other</strong>Things here</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>

</ul>"
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "Id key": "KE4I2-21",
    "Long desc": "<p color="red"><strong>Charger "15W" - Black</strong></p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe><strong>More</strong>:&nbsp;</p>\n\n<ul>\n\n<li><strong>List</li>\n\n<li><strong>M&auml;rke</strong>: SiGN</li>\n\n</ul>"
  },
  {
    "Id key": "LE0PP",
    "Long desc": "<p>Type-C charger<br /> - OnePlus 2<br /></p>\n\n<p><em>Warning</em></p>"
  },
  {
    "Id key": "T12-XRE2",
    "Long desc": "<h2>&nbsp;</h2>\n\n<h2><strong>Car Charger</strong></h2>\n\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>\n\n<p><strong>Assets:</strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\n<li><strong>Something</strong>Nice</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>\n\n<li><strong>Other</strong>Things here</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>\n\n</ul>"
  }
]
```

This is how the csvtojson package is parsing the csv file

```
const CSVToJSON = require("csvtojson");

(async () => {
  let descriptions = await CSVToJSON().fromFile("./desc.csv");
  console.log(descriptions)
})();

// Output
[
  {
    'Id key;Long desc': 'KE4I2-21;"<p color=""red""><strong>Charger "15W" - Black</strong></p>'
  },
  {
    'Id key;Long desc': '<iframe src=""https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX"" width=""560"" height=""315"" frameborder=""0"" allowfullscreen=""allowfullscreen""></iframe>'
  },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<p><strong>More</strong>:&nbsp;</p>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<ul>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<li><strong>List</li>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<li><strong>M&auml;rke</strong>: SiGN</li>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '</ul>"' },
  {
    'Id key;Long desc': 'LE0PP;"<p>Type-C charger<br /> - OnePlus 2<br /></p>'
  },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<p><em>Warning</em></p>"' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': 'T12-XRE2;"<h2>&nbsp;</h2>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<h2><strong>Car Charger</strong></h2>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<p><strong>Assets:</strong></p>' },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '<ul>' },
  {
    'Id key;Long desc': '<li><strong>Something</strong>Nice</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>'
  },
  {
    'Id key;Long desc': '<li><strong>Other</strong>Things here</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>'
  },
  { 'Id key;Long desc': '</ul>"' }
]
```

Comment: Where and by which software was this CSV file generated? It looks like "invalid" CSV in that the convention for text fields with embedded special characters such as ", ;, CR etc. is to enclose the field content in double quotes and duplicate embedded double quotes to escape them. This is violated in the Charger "15W" case. You might want to talk the provider of that file to use something that is unambiguously parseable instead of CSV which is inherently problematic.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: You updated the question but didn't address my comment about the invalid CSV and its origin. You might find some heuristic to "fix" the broken input in some cases but the right place to fix broken data is at the place where it is produced, not at the place where it is consumed.

Comment: If you are looking for a quick and dirty way of cleaning this up you could start by splitting on a 3 character string ;”< p then doing stuff like going back to find the characters up to a “ and so on. Revolting but will get you started.

Comment: @AHaworth Thanks, I managed to do it the "dirty" way. I'll add an answer soon. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a "dirty" way to parse the CSV file into a valid JSON array of objects.

```
let desc = fs.readFileSync("./files/TD-products-beskrivning html.csv", "utf-8");
  desc = desc
    .replace(/Id key;Long desc/g, "")
    .replace(/\r/g, " ")
    .replace(/\n/g, " ")
    .replace(/""/g, "'")
    .replace(/    /g, " ");
  desc = desc.split(';"');
  
  let ids = [];

  desc.forEach(element => {
    let n = element.split(" ");
    ids.push(n[n.length - 1]);
  });

  // Remove empty id & desc
  ids.pop();
  desc.shift();

  let descriptions = []

  for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    let descriptionObject = {};
    descriptionObject["Id key"] = ids[i];
    descriptionObject["Long desc"] = desc[i];
    descriptions.push(descriptionObject);
  }

  console.log(descriptions);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "Id key": "KE4I2-21",
    "Long desc": "<p color='red'><strong>Charger '15W' - Black</strong></p><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXX' width='560' height='315' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='allowfullscreen'></iframe><strong>More</strong>:&nbsp;</p>\n\n<ul>\n\n<li><strong>List</li>\n\n<li><strong>M&auml;rke</strong>: SiGN</li>\n\n</ul>"
  },
  {
    "Id key": "LE0PP",
    "Long desc": "<p>Type-C charger<br /> - OnePlus 2<br /></p>\n\n<p><em>Warning</em></p>"
  },
  {
    "Id key": "T12-XRE2",
    "Long desc": "<h2>&nbsp;</h2>\n\n<h2><strong>Car Charger</strong></h2>\n\n<p>Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>\n\n<p><strong>Assets:</strong></p>\n\n<ul>\n\n<li><strong>Something</strong>Nice</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>\n\n<li><strong>Other</strong>Things here</strong>&nbsp;Ja</li>\n\n</ul>"
  }
]
```